# Protecting function names in R

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to protect function names (or variables in general) so that they cannot be masked.

I recently spotted that this can be a problem when creating a data frame with the name "new", which masked a function used by lmer and thus stopped it working.  (Recovery is easy once you know what the problem is, here "rm(new)" did it.)

Comment: A data frame cannot overwrite a function. You can use both at the same time.

Comment: "Overwrite" was the wrong word.  Mask?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936748/declaring-a-const-variable-in-r

Answer (score 9):

There is an easy workaround for your problem, without worrying about protecting variable names (though playing with `lockBinding` does look fun).  If a function becomes masked, as in your example, it is still possible to call the masked version, with the help of the `::` operator.

In general, the syntax is `packagename::variablename`.

(If the function you want has not been exported from the package, then you need three colons instead, `:::`.  This shouldn't apply in this case however.)

Comment: Doesn't work if I'm calling a function, in a package, which relies on a function elsewhere which inadvertently has become masked.

Comment: @AndyF yeah that's a good point. I'm seeing a theme in the answers: R does not protect users from themselves. This is very Linux-like. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use environments! This is a great way to separate namespaces. For example:

```
> a <- new.env()
> assign('printer', function(x) print(x), envir=a)
> get('printer', envir=a)('test!')
[1] "test!"
```

Answer (score 2):

@hdallazuanna recommends [(via Twitter)](http://twitter.com/hdallazuanna/status/20831090972)

```
new <- 1
lockBinding('new', globalenv())
```

this makes sense when the variable is user created but does not, of course, prevent overwriting a function from a package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the reverse problem from the OP, and I wanted to prevent my custom functions in `.Rprofile` from being overridden when I defined a variable with the same name as a function, but I ended up putting my functions to `~/.R.R` and I added these lines to `.Rprofile`:

```
if("myfuns"%in%search())detach("myfuns")
source("~/.R.R",attach(NULL,name="myfuns"))
```

From the help page of `attach`:

```
One useful ‘trick’ is to use ‘what = NULL’ (or equivalently a
length-zero list) to create a new environment on the search path
into which objects can be assigned by assign or load or
sys.source.

...

## create an environment on the search path and populate it
sys.source("myfuns.R", envir = attach(NULL, name = "myfuns"))
```