# How can an error message be used by multiple functions?

Tags: r

How can I create a standard error message in R? For example, if multiple functions should return the following error message in some condition:

```
stop("This is an error")
```

My first thought was creating something like:

```
err_fun = function() stop("This is an error")
foo = function(a){ if(!a) err_fun()}
```

But this approach doesn't point the error location correctly (which makes sense)

```
 foo(FALSE)
 #Error in err_fun() : This is an error
```

The expected outcome would be

```
#Error in foo(FALSE) : This is an error
```

How to I properly write a "shortcut" for an error message so I don't have to write it every time and have a cleaner code?

Comment: Just use a variable? Or a sort-of [constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936748/1255289).