# How to make an R object immutable?

Tags: r, dataframe, immutability

I am trying to create an immutable data-frame in R.
Something like

```
df = iris
df = make_immutable(df)

df = df[1:100,] #gives error because df is now immutable
```

Is there any such function in R, like `make_immutable`, which can restrict an R object from further modifications during the session?

`Context:`
I have a machine learning pipeline which has a component written by a fellow developer who is modifying a data-frame in-place at multiple places. I want to restrict the modification of this data frame after some point. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring a Const Variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936748/declaring-a-const-variable-in-r)

Comment: Yes. `lockBinding("df", .GlobalEnv)` works. Thank you @Clemsang.